# Java collections sort method for string is not working properly for case sensitive and special characters

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I was working on sorting a list of String in Java (1.8) and came to know that it is not working as expected!

I am trying the following code for sorting:

```
private Set<String> getTestData() {
    Set<String> compRoles = new HashSet<>();
    compRoles.add("AA");
    compRoles.add("Aa");
    compRoles.add("aA");
    compRoles.add("aa");
    compRoles.add("11");
    compRoles.add("117");
    compRoles.add("12");
    compRoles.add("21");
    compRoles.add("!@");
    compRoles.add("@!");
    compRoles.add("@@!");
    compRoles.add("BB");
    compRoles.add("Bb");
    compRoles.add("bb");
    return compRoles;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<String> test = new ArrayList<>(new Test().getTestData());
    System.out.println(test);
    Collections.sort(test);
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

**Before sort:** `[AA, Aa, aA, aa, 11, BB, Bb, bb, 12, @!, @@!, 117, 21, !@]`

**After sort:** `[!@, 11, 117, 12, 21, @!, @@!, AA, Aa, BB, Bb, aA, aa, bb]`

**My expectation is:** `[!@, @!, @@!, 11, 117, 12, 21, aa, aA, Aa, AA, bb, Bb, BB]`

Do I need to use something else other that natural sort for this?

Comment: so, for you 'a' comes before 'A' .. ok. well, you'll need to write your own sorting logic, but it 'll be pretty broad. you'll actually have to compare char by char. good luck.

Comment: The answer is in the question. Given that the natural ordering doesn't order elements as you would like to, you need something else.

Comment: This is already implemented in jQuery sort. 
https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4

But I don't the the algo they are using!
Because of this UI and back-end is not in sync.
Any idea on this?

Comment: The unicode of ! is smaller than that of @ , unicode of @ is small than 1, unicode of 1 is smaller than A, uncicode of A is smaller than a. Hope it answers for the output that you get. Now If you need sorting as per your ordering , implement your comparator.

Comment: @nits.kk: I am totally agree with the answer given by jaspreet.
We can solve this issue by using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the [Collator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) class of Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> test = new ArrayList<>(new Test().getTestData());
    System.out.println(test);
    test.sort(Collator.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

Output:-

```
[AA, Aa, aA, aa, 11, BB, Bb, bb, 12, @!, @@!, 117, 21, !@]
[!@, @!, @@!, 11, 117, 12, 21, aa, aA, Aa, AA, bb, Bb, BB]
```

Comment: Now days the `List` class has its own `sort` method, so going through is an unnecessary step. It is a little bit clearer to write the code like this: `list.sort(Collator.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));`.

Comment: Thanks @Lii . Updated the answer. I didn't read he was working in Java 8 so answered Collections.sort instead of list.sort

Comment: It not always clear what Java version to target in our answers. But Java 8 has been out almost 5 years now! I think we can safely assume that that is the standard. Now days you can even declare your list like this: `var test = new ArrayList<>(new Test().getTestData());`

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom [comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for your sorting logics. After this you can use it like this:

```
Collections.sort(yourArrayList, new YourComparator());
```

Comment: Appropriate your answer. I know the use of comparator and comparable. I am looking for the logic or algorithm used behind this.

Comment: Then you question should look like you need  a custom comparator, and should contain question about sorting algortims. The easiest way is to have weights for each letter and compare them in your way.